# Tax on graduate research assistant salary paycheck in California

Tags: united-states, taxes, california

I have been admitted to an University of California program. They are giving me $2209 graduate research assistantship salary per month. How much can I expect to make after taxes in California on the student pay check? I heard I do not have to pay medicare and FICA.

I am a citizen of India and will be on F1 status. I was previously on F1 visa for $5+$ years and have claimed FICA exemption before.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.tax-rates.org/income-tax-calculator/

### Taxation

$2209 * 12 months

**$26,508.00 gross income**

### Deductions

(check for your situation, assuming 1 person)

(Head Of Household)
California: ($3,841.00)
Federal: ($8,950.00)

(One dependant)
Federal: ($3,900.00)

(One filer exemption)
California: ($102.00)

### Taxable Income

```
California     Federal
$22,565.00  $13,658.00
```

### Taxes:

```
California      Federal
$467.26         $1,411.20
```

FICA Tax 
($1,643.50)

Medicare Tax 
($384.37)

### Gross Tax

```
California     Federal
$467.26         $3,439.07
```

### Owed Tax

```
California     Federal
$467.26         $3,439.07
-------------------------    
California      Federal (Without FICA & Medicare)
$467.26         $1,411.20
```

### After tax income

```
Annual:
$22,601.67
$24629.54 (Without FICA & Medicare)

Monthly:
$1883.47
$2052.46 (Without FICA & Medicare)
```

Comment: do internationals have to pay fica?